# Adjoint of $L^{1}$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about $L^{p}$ spaces.

**Question:**
Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Let us consider $f \in L^{1}(X)$ satisfying the following property:
\begin{align*}
\forall g \in L^{1}(X) \cap L^{\infty}(X), \int_{X}fgd\mu=0
\end{align*}
This implies $f=0$ ?

**My attempt:**

**If $L^{1}(X)\cap L^{\infty}(X)$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(X)$ holds** then we can obtain the following statement:
\begin{align*}
\forall g \in L^{\infty}(X), \int_{X}fgd\mu=0
\end{align*}
This implies $f=0$ (by Hahn-Banach's theorem). Can we show that $L^{1}(X)\cap L^{\infty}(X)$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(X)$?

Comment: $L^1(X)$ is not dense in $L^\infty(X)$ in general. (eg $X = \mathbb R$ with measure $dx$. Then there is no $g\in L^1 \cap L^\infty$ so that $||g- 1||_\infty <0.5$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, it is not true in general that $L^1(X)\cap L^\infty(X)$ is dense in $L^\infty(X)$.

Indeed, we can use "the standard way" to deal with your question.

First of all, for each $g \in L^1(X)\cap L^\infty(X)$, consider

$$\text{sgn}(f) g =\begin{cases} g & \text{ if } f>0 \\-g & \text{ if } f<0\end{cases}$$

Then $\text{sgn}(f) g \in L^1(X) \cap L^\infty(X)$, and

$$ 0 = \int_X f (\text{sgn}(f) g) d\mu = \int_X |f| g. $$

Thus $|f|$ also satisfies your condition. Now we can show $f = 0$ $\mu$ a.e. by showing $|f| = 0$ $\mu$ a.e.. Assume not. Consider the set $A = \{ |f| >0\}$, we have

$$A = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} \left\{ |f| \ge 1/n\right\}$$

then there is $n$ so that $\mu(\left\{ |f| \ge 1/n\right\}) >0$. This set (call it $B$) is of finite measure, as $|f|\in L^1(X)$. Thus $1_B \in L^1(X) \cap L^\infty(X)$ and

$$ \int_X |f| 1_B d\mu = \int_B |f| d\mu > \frac 1n \mu(B) >0,$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. Your proof is easy to understand.